# Add (XY) Data in ArcMap is not finding folder connection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm trying to add XY data to ArcMap but it is working.
I tried several times to connect to the folder but it is not being connected and the windows appears empty afterwards

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Connect to D drive not the folder, or D:\GIS is as far as I would go down... is the folder hidden? Try copy/paste the path from explorer into the dialog box.

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to detail the precise steps that you have performed, please?  As it stands your pictures leave me trying to guess in a couple of places.

Comment: I'd rename it to survey_2015

Comment: What type of data are you trying to add? Shape files, csv, etc...You may just need to change the filter in the Add Data dialog.

Comment: It appears to be a local disk, so network/USB issues shouldn't apply. Can you show a screenshot of your ArcCatalog window? That should show folder connections near the top. It's not clear if you're successfully connecting or not from the first image, and you should be seeing *something* in the dropdown in the second image regardless of whether you can see the desired folder. Felix: starting the folder name with a number shouldn't be an issue - most of my data is stored that way. Evil: in the Add XY dialog, there are no filters to select, it's just 'Tables' and whatever recognized types.